# Edge/corner guard for a vinyl tube?

Tags: plumbing, condensate

I have a vinyl tube that runs from condensate drain pump in the basement through the floor into a washer standpipe. It goes over 1-2 corners (not sharp ones) but the vinyl tube still looks very susceptible to pinching, see picture:

[image]

Even if I manage to make a large bend such that there is no bend, I am afraid that over time it could still happen.

I am thinking of plugging a "plastic guide" on top of it would make sure it that it does not pinch. Does something like this exist or is there any other good solution?

Comment: Something like a spring fitted over the top of the tubing should work as an anti-kink device.

Comment: That looks promising, thanks!

Comment: Or a double barb fitting...definitely available in 90º, YMMV if you need 45º.

Comment: Not sure if it would fit, but they do make such things for PEX tubing at minimum bend radius for PEX tubing.  Switching to braid-reinforced tubing should also help.